# Diplay differents names for a list of checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ViewModel with a List of booleans. The idea is to display a bunch of checkboxes without defining all of them separately. like this :

**UsersViewModel.cs :**

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public bool[] Access { get; set; }
}
```

then I can display them like this :

**Users.cshtml :**

```
for (int i=0; i< m.Access.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Access[i])
}
```

But now I want to add a tag `[Display(Name = "some label")]` and have a different label for each of my checkboxes by adding the code line `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Users[i])` and passing an array of string in the display(Name) tag. For example :

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = { "First checkbox", "Second checkbox", "Third checkbox" })]
    public bool[] Access { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use wrapper class to store the display name and bool value in the class
and create a property of Checkbox class instead of bool

```
  public class UsersViewModel
    {
        public CheckBox[] Access { get; set; }
    }



   /// <summary>
    /// wrapper model for display name and bool value
    /// </summary>
    public class CheckBox
    { 
        public CheckBox(string dName,bool access)
        {
            Display = dName;
            Access = access;
        }
       [Required]
       public bool Access { get; set;}
       public string Display { get; set; }
    }
```

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
                ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
                var a= new List<CheckBox> {  };
                a.Add(new CheckBox("c1", true));
                a.Add(new CheckBox("c2", false));
                a.Add(new CheckBox("c3", true));
                ViewBag.checks =a;

                UsersViewModel usersViewModel = new UsersViewModel();
                usersViewModel.Access = a.ToArray();
                return View(usersViewModel);
    }
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Access.Length; i++)
                {

                    @Html.Label(Model.Access[i].Display)
                    @Html.CheckBox(Model.Access[i].Display, Model.Access[i].Display);
                }
```

***Update By using reflection***

you can use reflection also to read the display name
create a custom attribute

```
public class CustomDisplayName : Attribute
{
    public string [] Name { get; set;}
}
```

**UserViewModel.cs**
    public class UsersViewModel
    {

```
    //public CheckBox[] Access { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [CustomDisplayName(Name =  new string[] { "First checkbox", "Second checkbox", "Third checkbox" })]
    public bool[] Access1 { get; set; }
    public string[] DisplayName { get; }
    public UsersViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName=GetAttribute(typeof(UsersViewModel)).ToArray();
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> GetAttribute(Type t)
    {
        PropertyInfo props = typeof(UsersViewModel).GetProperties().First(x=>x.Name=="Access1");
        return props.GetCustomAttribute<CustomDisplayName>().Name.ToList();
    }
}
```

**Index Action**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UsersViewModel usersViewModel = new UsersViewModel();
        usersViewModel.Access1 = new bool[] {true,false,true };
        return View(usersViewModel);
    }
```

**index.cshtml**

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Access1.Length; i++)
    {

        @Html.CheckBox(Model.DisplayName[i], Model.Access1[i]);
    }
```